# python3 class method to update dictionary

Tags: python

I am new at programming and python.  I am currently trying to create a budget program that has 3 dictionaries.  with a function I get it rite to update the input data from a user to update my dictionary.  I looked all over and can not seem to find the correct answer how to use a class method to update my dictionary.  If i add the information b.add('name','amount') it works but if I do it from the keyboard asking for input it only ouptuts the last entry.  Hope this make sense.  My code

```
class MyClass():

    def __init__(self, name, amount):

        self.dic = {}
        self.name = name
        self.amount = amount
    def add(self, d):
        self.dic[self.name] = self.amount
        return self.dic

    def show(self, d):        
        dic = {}
        dic.update(self.dic)
        return dic
b = {}

while True: 

    name = input("Name")

    amount = input("amount")

    b = MyClass(name, amount)
    b.add(b)
    print (b.add(b))
    print(b.show(b))
```

I am a blind person and to know how to use a class method to update my programs dictionary to view later.

Comment: can you please reformat your code so we know what you're trying to do?

Comment: "I am a blind person" - as in literally blind? Your code formatting is off, but I'm not sure how you'd be able to tell if you can't see it. I don't know how screen readers interact with code formatting.

Comment: `dic = {}
        dic.update(self.dic)` should be `dic = self.dic.copy()` if you want to create a copy.

Comment: What is that `d` parameter on all of your methods for? You're always passing the instance itself, and then never doing anything with it.

Comment: Sorry if format is a bit of using notepad++ and yes totally blind.  Tried the copy and did not work.  What happens is it give me the last entry ii entered and that is all.  What i need is every entry i enter even if the name is there to make a dictionary and keep adding into the dictionary.  so if I enter a name and a age for 10 people all 10 must be in the dictionary where now it only display the last entry i have entered.  With a function I got it rite by passing the dictionary to the function that is why the d is at the end of my def sstatement for I tried passing it like that also

Comment: Figured it out.  Thank you very much and at the end the copy did work.  Thanks a lot